# Does using the same curve certificate on both ends cause security issues?

Tags: certificates, man-in-the-middle, ecc

I have the following scenario: an application that establishes a full mesh connection with itself on a remote server. We use 0MQ and curve certificates for security and authentication, but at the same time we use the same certificate on both ends.

Does this cause any security issues with respect to the Man-in-the-middle attack?

Comment: How do you protect private parameters? Server is suppose to use public part, including curve's type.

Comment: We don't expose the private key, that is stored securely on the application. We do send the public key. So given that the private key is safe and secure, is there another way for the man-in-the-middle attack?

Comment: The it this regards you probably provide pub certificate to the server and it is uses ec pub key to validate device generated signatures. In this case you have to be sure that public certificate is valid and the issuer is trusted. See chain of trust. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_of_trust

Comment: Going back to your original question, yes same elliptic curve is used on both ends and selecting the curve is one of the initial steps. This is not a threat. But you have to make sure that certificate belongs to you and not someone else.